# How can I implement an additional layer of expiring-token-based authorisation in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, authorization, servicestack

We have a mobile app with ServiceStack-based cookie authentication. The app stores the user's login cookie and keeps itself logged in if the user so desires.

We have a 'Purchase PIN' feature in the app - the user can set a PIN and require it to be entered every time they make a purchase. The intention is to guard against purchases being made on a stolen or mislaid unlocked phone.

The app has a settings/configuration view in which, amongst other things, the user can set and turn on and off the purchase PIN. We therefore need to force the user to re-authenticate to be able to edit their settings.

Our thinking is that when the user tries to enter the settings page:

- The app requires the user to re-authenticate with their password.
- In response, the API issues a token back to the app. The token represents some secret that only the API knows, plus the user ID, plus an expiry timestamp in the near future.
- All user-settings-related API calls require a valid token to be sent in the request.
- The API validates that the token was issued for the same user, and checks that the timestamp is still good.
- If the API finds that the token isn't valid or has expired, it responds with a signal that the UI should have the user re-authenticate to obtain a new token before continuing.

This all has to live outside / alongside the existing ServiceStack cookie authentication (reworking our current auth layer is outside scope and timeline for various reasons).

What's the best practice for implementing this additional level of security in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want look at the [WebSudoFeature Plugin](https://docs.servicestack.net/plugins#web-sudo) which allows a privileged protected service to force the user having to re-authenticate in order to be able to access Services annotated with `[WebSudoRequired]`.

As for the expiring token I'd implement that as a separate App Layer security feature passed as a Request DTO property into your Service instead of trying to integrate it with ServiceStack's top-level authentication.

For its implementation you could [create a JWT Token manually](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#creating-jwt-tokens-manually) which you could validate in your App or you could generate a DB entry with a UUID/Guid PK that contains the expiry as you may want this to maintain audit info (e.g. time/IP) when these PIN authorized tokens are used rather using a stateless Token without any audit history.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - we've gone with a stateless JWT token sent in the DTO and all seems to be working nicely (may add some auditing, but probably directly in the service calls).